# Где размещать базу данных для веб приложений?

Tags: spring, java-ee, spring-boot

Добрый день.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нужно разместить БД для веб приложения которое будет размещено на облаке? веб приложение сделано на Spring Boot.
До этого делал и включал исключительно на своем компьютере с включенной базе на компе.

Comment: на сервере, а в приложение прописать доступ к базе на сервере (host, user, password, database)

Answer (score 0):

Желательно, чтобы база данных была максимально близко к веб-приложению, для уменьшения задержек передачи.

Следовательно ее следует разместить в облаке рядом с веб-приложением.